# How to address a tree in a recursive function

Tags: c, arrays, recursion, binary-tree

I already have a binary tree(not balanced) and each node already has a *team associeted to it. However, when I try to turn the tree into a array, there's a problem with the address at `TreeToVector(Teamtree->Left,...)`. How should I address it?

```
typedef struct
{
    char *team;

}Team;

typedef struct Hash_tree *TreePointer;

typedef struct Hash_tree
{
        TreePointer Right;
        TreePointer Left;
        Team T;
}Hash_tree;

void TreeToVector(Hash_tree **Teamtree, Team *t, int sizeofarray, int i)
{
    if(Teamtree == NULL) return;
    else
    {
        t[i].team = (*Teamtree)->T.team;
        i++;
    if(Teamtree->Left != NULL && i < sizeofarray)
             i = TreeToVector(Teamtree->Left, t, sizeofarray, i);
    if(Teamtree->Right != NULL && i < size)
             i = TreeToVector(Teamtree->Right, t, sizeofarray, i);

    }
}
```

In main.c:

```
Team t[size];
TreeToVector(Teamtree, t, size, 0);
```

Comment: That should not even *build* much less run. What does `i = TreeToVector(...)` do when `TreeToVector` doesn't return anything?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I've changed the code, may I edit the question or should I post it as a comment?

Comment: Please edit your question to show a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Looks like `(*Teamtree)->T.team` and `Teamtree->Left` (and Right) do not match in levels of `Teamtree` indirection. Which would explain the *"there's a problem with the address at `TreeToVector(Teamtree->Left`,...)"* error.

Answer (score 1):

Because you don't return the new value, your `i` is getting reset as you jump up & down the levels. You can return it or another way would be to make it `static` and reset it somehow as you first enter the function (or just keep it outside the function). Alternatively pass it in as a pointer so you can update the same value.

By way of example, if you take the case where the first node has a left and a right then you can clearly see the same `i` is going to be passed to the `TreeToVector` calls unless you change it.

Comment: I'm fairly certain the problem is elsewhere. If `Teamtree` is type `Hash_tree **`, where do `Teamtree->Left` and `Teamtree->Right` point?

Answer (score -1):

```
int TreeToVector(TreePointer tree, Team *t, int sizeofarray, int i)
{
    if(tree == NULL) return i;

    t[i++].team = tree->T.team;

    // Travel left tree
    if(i < sizeofarray)
             i = TreeToVector(tree->Left, t, sizeofarray, i);

    // Travel right tree
    if(i < sizeofarray)
             i = TreeToVector(tree->Right, t, sizeofarray, i);

    // Return current index of t
    return i;
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't work -- you can't return from a `void` function.